# validate the individual property of viewmodel using data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to built multiple file upload using view model and data annotation. Following is view model:

```
 public class UploadNewsModel
{
[File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase GenearlNews { get; set; }

        [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
      public HttpPostedFileBase SportNews { get; set; }

        [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
      public HttpPostedFileBase BusiNews { get; set; }

        [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
      public HttpPostedFileBase InterNews { get; set; }

        [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
      public HttpPostedFileBase EntertaintNews { get; set; }
        }
```

**Problem:**
Here, I want to check model state of individual property to show the error in individual validation error. I have no idea to check for individual whereas for all viewmodel we use **ModelState.IsValid** I have following action:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(UploadNewsModel newsmodel)
{

    HttpPostedFileBase general = newsmodel.GenearlNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase sport = newsmodel.SportNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase business = newsmodel.BusiNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase international = newsmodel.InterNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase entertainment = newsmodel.EntertaintNews;


    if (general.ContentLength > 0 && general != null && ...check generalnews validation using data annotation == valid.. )
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(general.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/News/General News/"), fileName);
        general.SaveAs(path);
    }
    else
    {
        .... add error of data annotation plus  below
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }

     ......... same for remaining upload file
    return View(newsmodel);
}
```

**View:**

```
    @model IVRControlPanel.Models.UploadNewsModel

  @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "NewsUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form1", @id = "form1", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {


       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GenearlNews, new {  type = "file" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenearlNews)
          ........... same for remaining file upload
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the error message, you will need to check for Isvalid:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(UploadNewsModel newsmodel)
{
    // If not Valid
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return this.View(newsmodel);
    }
    HttpPostedFileBase general = newsmodel.GenearlNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase sport = newsmodel.SportNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase business = newsmodel.BusiNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase international = newsmodel.InterNews;
    HttpPostedFileBase entertainment = newsmodel.EntertaintNews;


    if (general.ContentLength > 0 && general != null && ...check generalnews validation using data annotation == valid.. )
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(general.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/News/General News/"), fileName);
        general.SaveAs(path);
    }
    else
    {
        .... add error of data annotation plus  below
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }

     ......... same for remaining upload file
    return View(newsmodel);
}
```

This way it should only display errors of files posted;
If you want all 5 fields to be filled, you will need to add [Required]:

```
[Required]
     [File(AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".tiff", ".png", ".pdf" }, MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 8, ErrorMessage = "Invalid File")]
          public HttpPostedFileBase SportNews { get; set; }
```

** You will not be able to check every property separately for the validation, but with the isValid you will notify the user of the incorrect file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UploadNewsModel` doesn't have any properties for `Username`/`Password` so where exactly do you get those from?

If you only want to allow authorized access to your controller action then you should use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

```
[HttpPost]  
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(UploadNewsModel newsmodel)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this Username/Pass is a copy paste error message from another part of his code